Syncfusion ejs-grid custom filter datasource
I am working with a syncfusion grid with a datasource containing ~30,000 rows. When using the checkbox filter for simple lookup columns, the server-side query is slow and misses options if not in the first 1000 records. I would like to create a separate simple datasource for these lookup columns.
Is this possible?

You can customize the list items of the CheckBox filter for specific columns. This can be achieved by assigning a custom dataSource to the filter module in the "actionBegin" event for the requestType "filterBeforeOpen". Please refer to the below knowledge base for more information:
KB: https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/10065/how-to-change-the-data-source-for-checkbox-filter-popup-in-grid
Note: Make sure to provide the dataSource for the Filter Model as an array of objects with the key being the column field and the value that needs to be displayed in the CheckBox list.

This worked well for a simple lookup but did not work for a complex lookup where the column name is ConfactInfo.CityId. Any suggestions for that?
